# Use MarkerPlace with Google Maps JS API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display a marker for a specific place according to [the reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerPlace):

```
var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(29.5528437, -95.0953803);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('my-map'), {
  zoom: 12,
  center: pos
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  place: {
    placeId: 'ChIJc29kHLCdQIYRpK0NUf9HKCE'
  },
  title: 'NASA',
  visible: true
});
```

However, this error occurs:

```
InvalidValueError: setPlace: in property location: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object
```

How can I display a marker for a place instead of a position?

---

Edit: I tried with

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  place: new google.maps.MarkerPlace({
    placeId: 'ChIJc29kHLCdQIYRpK0NUf9HKCE'
  }),
  title: 'NASA',
  visible: true
});
```

but now I get the error

```
TypeError: google.maps.MarkerPlace is not a constructor
```

I am using version 3.28.14.

Comment: Have you tried `place: new google.maps.MarkerPlace({placeId: 'ChIJc29kHLCdQIYRpK0NUf9HKCE'})` ?

Comment: @abeyaz I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see you are using experimental features but you dont include  proper library file. Load the file like this, `v=3.exp` is the important part here.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=YOUR_API_KEY">
```

Comment: Still the same problem, and `google.maps.MarkerPlace` is still undefined.

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions it must work. But i also tried and its not working. I think there is a bug on Google's side.